# implicit instantiation of undefined template: basic_fstream<string>

Tags: c++

I'm compiling this on macOS using clang/llvm 8.0.0. Compiling for C++14.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

basic_fstream<string> open_file(string file);

int main()
{
    basic_fstream<string> f = open_file("test");
    f.close();
}

basic_fstream<string> open_file(string file) {
    basic_fstream<string> f;
    f.open(file);

    if(!f.is_open()) {
        f.clear();
        f.open(file, ios_base::out);
        f.close();
        f.open(file);
    }

    return f;
}
```

It produces a long error list but the first is:

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::codecvt<std::__1::basic_string<char>, char, __mbstate_t>'
__always_noconv_ = __cv_->always_noconv();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template parameter to `basic_fstream` is a character type, not a string type. The typical character types that are supported by a C++ implementation would be `basic_fstream<char>` and `basic_fstream<wchar_t>`, for example.

But why use this template? Just use `std::fstream`, a.k.a. `std::basic_fstream<char>`; or `std::wfstream`, a.k.a. `std::basic_fstream<wchar_t>`.

It also wouldn't hurt to [get rid of `using namespace std;` while your at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), too.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Are char and wchar the only charT's defined, and what are the requirements to be a charT? And don't worry, using namespace std was only for the example

Comment: The C++ standard specifies only `char` and `wchar_t`, but a given C++ implementation is permitted to support other character types, of course.

Comment: Ok so it's not a thing you can make a class of yourself, it would have to implemented beforehand?

Comment: It will have to be implemented by your C++ library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: C++11 added new standard `char16_t` and `char32_t` character types, to help people get away from the portability issues of `wchar_t`. Whether a given library implements STL classes that support those new types is another issue.